# gmock Multiple mock instances, but only one is effective

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I would like to test a class (*Controller*) that manages a set of entities of a certain kind. Entities are created internally in this class because a factory would be an overkill here, so here is how I inject mocks into it:

```
class TestController : public Controller {
public:
    /* Mechanism for a mock injection */
    std::shared_ptr<IEntity> create_entity() override {
        return temp_entity;
    }

    /* Variable to hold the entity being injected */
    std::shared_ptr<IEntity> temp_entity;
};
```

Production code invokes ***create_entity()*** in the *Controller* class, which I overload here, and adds the result to a container. *temp_entity* is the way I supply my mocks and the test, where I supply two distinct mock instances, looks like this:

```
class MockEntity : public IEntity {
    MOCK_METHOD0(perform_operation, bool());
}

TEST(ControllerTest, TestFailure) {
    std::shared_ptr<TestController> controller = std::make_shared<TestController>();

    std::shared_ptr<MockEntity> entity1 = std::make_shared<MockEntity>();
    controller->temp_entity = entity1;
    controller->add_entity(); // This invokation fetches the result of create_entity()

    std::shared_ptr<MockEntity> entity2 = std::make_shared<MockEntity>();
    controller->temp_entity = entity2;
    controller->add_entity(); // This invokation fetches the result of create_entity()

    EXPECT_CALL(*entity1, perform_operation().WillOnce(::testing::Return(true));
    EXPECT_CALL(*entity2, perform_operation().WillOnce(::testing::Return(false));

    controller->run();
}
```

***controller.run()*** only concurrently executes ***perform_operation()*** on each of the entities.

When the test is run, the function in the second expectation is called twice and the function in the first expectation is not run at all. I am sure that the controller operates on two distinct versions of an entity before ***executing run()*** function.

Is there a fundamental problem in what I am trying to do? How can I separate my expectations for these two mocks in a test? I tried creating two distinct mock classes with ***perform_operation()*** method being implemented in the mock body and when running the test in the debugger I still hit the method of one mock class twice.

Comment: @Soeren I am embarassed for wasting your time on typos. I have created two implementations for the _perform_operation()_ in the following manner:
`class TestEntity1 : public IEntity {
    bool perform_operation() { std::cout << "1"; }
}
class TestEntity2 : public IEntity {
    bool perform_operation() { std::cout << "2"; }
}`

_perform_operation_ was invoked, but only on one of the test classes, so I received th output of the form "22".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test looks correct and the way, how you inject the mocks into the system under test, is an absolutely reasonable method.

I suppose, the critical issue is in your class under Test. I rebuild your Test with the following controller:

```
class Controller {
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<IEntity> create_entity() = 0;

    void add_entity() {
        auto entity = create_entity();
        entities.push_back(entity);
    }

    void run() {
        for(auto e : entities) {
            bool i =  e->perform_operation();
        }
    }
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IEntity> > entities;
};
```

With this class the test succeeded like expected.

Comment: My code is identical with only one difference: _perform_operation_ is run concurrently in separate threads using packaged_task. Production code has been manually tested and is working correctly, hence the reason I have been looking in the direction of gmock. I will convert my execution into a sequential one and see what happens then. I would assume you are running gmock 1.7.0? Is gtest 1.8.0 or 1.7.0?

Comment: On the other hand I have just realized that since I have added the concrete implementations of the methods and still had a problem, this has little to do with the framework now. Anyway I will get back after the sequential test :-)

Comment: You have been 100% right: the problem was in the function that spawned the threads. I have been using the following mechanism to wrap a function for a thread: `auto processor = std::bind(&IEntity::perform_operation, std::ref(entity)` when looping through all the elements of `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IEntity> > entities;`

I probably do not fully understand how std::bind works. The misbehavior occurs only when I bind the pointer by reference and the code works as expected when I remove `std::ref`.

Thanks for the help and for reviewing the test - I had nowhere to get advice from!